# Passing pointers down to three nested functions

Tags: c, pointers, cuda

I am working on a CUDA project. But, this is basically a C concept on pointers having not much to do with CUDA itself.

I am not sure if my referencing/dereferencing pointers are done correctly to reflect the new values on my `kernel` function  (same as a C function but done on GPU).

My `kernel` gets a pointer as parameter:

```
__global__ kernel(StructA *a)
{
  StructB b;
  foo1(&a, &b); // passing both addresses to foo1
                // I don't need to modify anything on StructA, might in future
                // But, I will assign values to StructB (in foo1 and foo2)
  ...
  // Work with StructB
  ...
}
```

Question for `foo1`: Should I give the address of the pointer-to pointer StructA in the call to `foo2`?

```
__device__ foo1(StructA **a, StructB *b) // pointer-to pointer and pointer
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if( (*a)->elem1[tid] ) // Access to value in elem1[tid]
    foo2(a, &b, tid);    // Pass structures to foo2
  ...
  b->elem3 = 1;          // Assign value to StructB
  ...
}
```

Questions for `foo2`: If I pass StructA address I will need a third level pointer for StructA. But, I am lost at that level of pointers.

```
__device__ foo2(StructA **a, StructB **b, int tid)
{
  // Assign value from elem2 in StructA for the thread to elem2 in StructB
  (*b)->elem2 = (*a)->elem2[tid]; // Assign value to StructB from StructA

  // HELP in previous line, not so sure if referencing the in the Structures
  // are done correctly.
  ...
}
```

I can paste my actual code, but didn't want to complicate things.

Comment: Why are you passing the pointer to pointer for `foo1()` or `foo2()`?

Comment: @Macattack because I need the assignments of values to be reflected on `kernel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be what you need.

```
 foo1(a, &b);

__device__ foo1(StructA *a, StructB *b)

   foo2(a, b, tid); //when we are inside foo1, foo1 has the pointers available 
    //so we just pass it to foo2.

__device__ foo2(StructA *a, StructB *b, int tid)
```

If you do `foo2(a, &b, tid);` in foo1, you are passing the address of the pointer variable that contains the pointer to the structure, but this is not necessary, as long as you have the pointer to the structure available in your function you can pass it around to other functions by simply saying

```
`function_name(structA *pointer_to_strucutA)
```

regarding the assignment what you have done is correct but not necessary

```
(*b)->elem2 = (*a)->elem2[tid]; //this is correct if you pass a pointer to pointer to struct
```

if you follow my code all you really need is

```
b->elem2 = a->elem2[tid];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I tend to overcomplicate things. The idea of pointer-to pointer passing was taken from "Understanding and Using C Pointers" O'Reilly 2013 by Richard Reese, on chapter 3 'Pointers and Functions' page 61 __Passing and Returning by Pointer__: "When the data is a pointer that needs to be modified, then we pass it as a pointer to a pointer".

Comment: @mrei exactly,"When the data is a pointer that needs to be modified, then we pass it as a pointer to a pointer" this is different from your case. the author wants to modify the pointer, not what it's pointing to, in this case to modify the pointer you would need to send a pointer to pointer. but your not modifying the pointer. think of a pointer like an house address, in programming terms the address is going to some memory and not the house, you can give this address to other people(passing the pointer to functions)

Comment: @tessaract I was thinking exactly what you wrote while posting my previous comment. Thanks!